# VBA code not running. Need to call string from different cells for function

Tags: vba, excel

I cant run my code. Please help. I need to call the strings from different cell values on different sheets in the same workbook.

```
Sub ll()
    Dim result_range As Range
    Dim tag, stime, filtexp, PIServer, boundarytype As String
    Dim numvals, outcode As Integer
    Dim pi_formula As String
    tag = "Sheets(""Tags"").Range(""A2"")"
    stime = "Sheets(""DATAEXTRACT"").Range(""A7"")"
    numvals = 1
    filtexp = "Sheets(""BatchConditions"").Range(""B23"")"
    PIServer = "SGSitePI"
    Mode = "inside"
    'PINCompFilDat(tag, stime, numvals,filtexp,filtcode,outcode,PIServer ,mode)
    pi_formula = "=PINCompFilDat(" & Chr(34) & tag & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & stime & Chr(34) & "," & _
                    Chr(34) & numvals & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & filtexp & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & fitcode & Chr(34) & "," & _
                    CStr(outcode) & "," & _
                    Chr(34) & PIServer & Chr(34) & "," & _
                    Chr(34) & Mode & Chr(34) & ")"
    Set result_range = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:B3")
    result_range.ClearContents
    result_range.FormulaArray = pi_formula
    result_range.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    result_range.Copy
    result_range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do - where is the code for `PINCompFilDat`?

Comment: I believe it's `PINCompFilDat(tagname, stime, numvals, filtexp, filtcode, outcode, PIServer, mode)` (defined on page 123 [here](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/um/hsedl-um024_-en-e.pdf))

Comment: `fitcode` should not enclosed in quotes as it is an integer. `filtexp` is *'A filter expression used to filter out results'*, not a string that looks like a range object address.

Comment: @Jeeped - Your Google-fu exceeds mine.

Comment: `numvals` is an integer as well; no wrapping quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `Sheets` collection from a worksheet function.  Your `pi_formula` variable is set to this:

```
=PINCompFilDat("Sheets("Tags").Range("A2")", _
               "Sheets("DATAEXTRACT").Range("A7")","1", _
               "Sheets("BatchConditions").Range("B23")","",0,"SGSitePI","inside")
```

This isn't the correct calling convention for the function (or even really that close - thanks, @Jeeped).

There are a couple of issues.  First, lines like this...

```
Dim numvals, outcode As Integer
```

...don't do what you expect.  *Each declaration* separated by commas on the same line has to be typed, otherwise it is considered a `Variant`.  It should look like this:

```
Dim numvals As Integer, outcode As Integer
```

Second, what you need to pass are *values*, not ranges. I'm assuming that `tag` , `stime`, and `filtexp` are supposed to be the values in `Sheets("Tags").Range("A2")`, `Sheets("DATAEXTRACT").Range("A7")`, and `Sheets("BatchConditions").Range("B23")`. If so, get the values, then build your function like you would type it on the worksheet (hint - `Debug.Print pi_formula`).

Third, as @Jeeped points out in the comments, the Integer parameters `numvals`, `filtexp`, and `outcode` should not be wrapped in quotes.

Finally, you never set a value for `fitcode` (or declare it). `Mode` is also not declared.  You can easily catch this type of error by typing `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

My best guess is that it should look something like this:

```
Sub ll()
    Dim result_range As Range
    Dim tag As String, stime As String, filtexp As String
    Dim PIServer As String, boundarytype As String
    Dim numvals As Integer, outcode As Integer, fitcode As Integer
    Dim pi_formula As String, Mode As String

    tag = Sheets("Tags").Range("A2").Value
    stime = Sheets("DATAEXTRACT").Range("A7").Value
    numvals = 1
    filtexp = Sheets("BatchConditions").Range("B23").Value
    PIServer = "SGSitePI"
    Mode = "inside"
    'fitcode = something or other.
    pi_formula = "=PINCompFilDat(" & Chr(34) & tag & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & stime & Chr(34) & "," & _
                    numvals & "," & Chr(34) & filtexp & Chr(34) & "," & fitcode & "," & _
                    CStr(outcode) & "," & _
                    Chr(34) & PIServer & Chr(34) & "," & _
                    Chr(34) & Mode & Chr(34) & ")"
    Set result_range = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:B3")
    result_range.ClearContents
    result_range.FormulaArray = pi_formula
    result_range.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    result_range.Copy
    result_range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```